# Include XML multi string in C program xCode

Tags: c, string

I'm wondering how to include a multi line string like an XML data inside a C string? I need to replace some text (MY_REPLACED_TEXT) inside the XML file.

So I include the xml like this:

```
char myXMLString = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
' <painting>'
'   <img src="madonna.jpg" alt="Foligno Madonna, by Raphael"/>'
'   <caption>MY_REPLACED_TEXT'
'   <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>'
'</painting>'
```

However, this doesnt seem to work (I get

```
"Expected ; after top level declarator" error
```

).

I've also tried escaping with \ at the end of the line, instead of the apostrophe ' but still not working (I get

```
"use of undeclared identifier" error
```

)

Is there a better way to include a string into a compiled C program? Can I include the XML as a file, which is local to the compiled program and search/replace that?

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
char *myXMLString = 
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
"<painting>"
"   <img src=\"madonna.jpg\" alt=\"Foligno Madonna, by Raphael\"/>"
"   <caption>MY_REPLACED_TEXT"
"   <date>1511</date>-<date>1512</date>.</caption>"
"</painting>";
```

Comment: Ahh i c, I was hoping there would be an easy way. My file is rather large. Maybe there is an online tool to escape things?

Comment: There are many examples in this site for information on how to replace the method and the string to read the file all.